# How to pass id(Parameter ) from one place to another in same page?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular4-forms, angular4-router

I am new to angular 2/4 projects. in this interface I get a popup search tab with editable list.

But I am not aware of the method to get data to main interface for edit after I click this list edit button.

Simply what I need is to pass the id of the current item to main edit view as a parameter.

**My code:**

[image]

**This is my TS file:**

```
 Editmodeclose(value: any) {
 { 
     let ItemID: number =this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['code'];

     alert(this.userid);
     alert(this.shopid);
     alert(this.ItemID);//(here item id show undefined)
     this._enqService.FetchStockitem(ItemID, this.shopid, this.userid).subscribe(defaultdatas => this.defaultdata = defaultdatas,
          error => {
                    console.error(error);
                    this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
                });
            $("#SearchModal").modal("hide");
        }
    }
```

My html

```
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-right">
                                <span class="btn btn-success Editmode-Btn" (click)="Editmodeclose()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<ng-container *ngFor="let items of defaultdata;">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/NewStockCount',items.ItemID]">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Item Code</label>
                                    <span>{{items.ItemCode}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Item Description</label>

                                    <span>{{items.ItemDescription}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>(....etc.......)
```

Comment: try to change your alert(this.ItemID);//(here item id show undefined) to
alert(ItemID);   //(here item id show undefined)

Comment: yes i also change like that.and in my console the item id is null

Comment: when you opening popup , pass Json to edit button method , then you will get data of entire row ,you can access value of which one you like

Comment: @AmitRai actually i am new to this so i dont know to pass json method

Comment: please share your html file where you define popup

Comment: @AmitRai ok  i will share

Comment: in Html  , you have line <ng-container *ngFor="let **items** of defaultdata;"> , where items is json for each line  , on pass this **items** and you can access it on ts file . for example in html file you call a function xyz(**items**); define xyz in ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181460/discussion-between-akhil-and-amit-rai).

Comment: @AmitRai i could not get the answer

Answer (score 1):

In edit button click, pass 'items' object => (click)="Editmodeclose(items)"

try like :-

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let items of defaultdata;">
.
.
.
.
<button (click)="Editmodeclose(items)">Edit Button</button>
</ng-container>
```

.ts file:-

```
Editmodeclose(value: any) {
 { 
     alert(value.userid);
     alert(value.shopid);
     alert(value.ItemID);//(here item id show undefined)
     this._enqService.FetchStockitem(value.ItemID, value.shopid, this.userid).subscribe(defaultdatas => this.defaultdata = defaultdatas,
          error => {
                    console.error(error);
                    this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
                });
            $("#SearchModal").modal("hide");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you move your search item popup code into a component(for example, searchItem.component.ts), and then include your component in your existing component. In your search component, use an event emitter(https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) for output. 
If you still want to stick to your existing implementation, you should write a (click) handler on your "edit" button, where you will set your id in your main component.

In your component ts file

```
selectedId: number;

selectItem(id: number){
this.selectedId = id;
}
```

In your html,

```
<button (click)="selectItem(items.id)">Your edit button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following check --

```
{ path: 'NewStockCount/:code', component: MyComponent } // Check you have right param name 'code'
```

You have declared the local variable

```
let ItemID: number =this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['code'];
```

but you are trying to use by `this` keyword which is using.
you should simply use `ItemID`

Here is the better way to handle the URL params

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       let code = params['code'];
       // execute these codes whenever param value changes
    });
  }
```

Comment: here already i tried using ItemID.but didnot get so i add this.Itemid

Comment: here i want to display the item id in same url or page

Comment: Post your URL routing declaration here -

Comment: ex : `{ path: 'NewStockCount/:code', component: MyComponent }`

Comment: { path: 'NewStockCount/:code', component: NewStockCountComponent },

Comment: Just put this in your `NewStockCount` and check if you are getting the params in log.
 `ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       let code = params['code'];
       console.log("params",params);
    });
  }`